# What is the proper use of exaptable?

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

I have an assignment and I want to say that by using cosine similarity and word2vec, the project can easily be repurposed for other use. Would it be accurate to say this?

> This project makes use of recommender systems in order to generate a personalised match (Vaidya, Khachane, 2017) for every student in XYZ. The selected recommender systems for XYZ app are cosine similarity and the word2vec model, chosen for their simplicity and efficiency in computation. Furthermore, using cosine similarity and word2vec makes XYZ app easily exaptable.

Comment: Exaptable is *not* a word.

Answer (score 3):

**Exaptable** is not found in most dictionaries; or indeed, any that I could find. [A google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22exaptable%22) shows that it's usually a misspelling of "acceptable" (the most common finding).

But in a [couple](https://books.google.com/books?id=BkuYCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA21&ots=_iVG_frPiS&dq=%22exaptable%22&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q=%22exaptable%22&f=false) [cases](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/talk.origins/CtLw-5JNYXk/DEO0fU1gCTUJ) it seems to be a back-formation from "[exaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exaptation)", a jargon term in evolutionary biology. By analogy with "adaptation/adaptable", just as something that is *adaptable* is subject to *adaption*, something that is *exaptable* is subject to *exaptation* - at least, that's how the few uses seem to be using it.

But it's exceedingly rare, and it's technical jargon, and it is probably best avoided (unless you are deliberately trying to use rare technical jargon) in favor of something like "externally adaptable".